# Some (healthy) NTFS-partitions suddenly won't mount

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount, kubuntu, ntfs

I had to re-install Kubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr). I used the same partition the same installation disk and I installed the same programs (except the Nvidia drivers, but that's a different story).

I have a lot of NTFS partitions on my system and through the last 1½ years I had all kind of problems but never NTFS issues. Well, sometimes deleted files remained as ".fuseXXXX" files but I wouldn't call that a "problem".

So, now, after installing the NTFS tools, I suddenly had errors on mounting 2 partitions in the middle of a disk. Here is an example of one error message:

```
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x00000000  size: 1024   usa_ofs: 0  usa_count: 65535: Das Argument ist ungültig
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 16).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd13': Eingabe-/Ausgabefehler
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

I already ran "CHKDSK /F" and even "/R" on these two partitions under Win7 with no errors detected. The Disk is relatively new and definitely NOT of the kind of cheep junk. Both partitions (sdd11 & sdd13) are same sized in-between other same sized partitions of the same format while regarding cylinder boundaries and running with no problems at all for very much longer than having Kubuntu on this machine and also running without any problems since running Kubuntu too – except this new installation of Kubuntu. Oh, both partitions are perfectly defragmented and also the stated $MFTMirr is valid. Nothing changed on these partitions for several months while running them without problems on prior Kubuntu installations as well as the Live-DVD.

The only thing that was different – *as far as I can remember* – was the order of the NTFS tools installation. This time I first installed "NTFS-3G" from the latest Tuxera package (last time I installed it from muon and updated later from Tuxera) and then installed the "NTFS-config" tool (which I installed last time before "NTFS-3G").

What can I do?

Comment: Since a very long time I never install additional NTFS tools and everything works as it should, NTFS partitions internal or external and others. And if you need something else always prefer the versions in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Say, do you know if I can completely remove the "ntfs-config" tool including the changes it made to the system by simply running "apt-get purge"? Actually I'm a little nervous on that because last time I ran purge on "wine*" it ruined my system completely.

Comment: Do they mount if you run a live DVD/USB of the same OS?

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine with the Live-DVD. I used the same disk for all my installations. Just this time it caused problems. The only difference is the order of NTFS-tool installation which – as far as I learned from Linux – shouldn't really be a problem. Is there maybe a file included in the official Ubuntu version of "NTFS-3G" for Trusty that is _not_ included in the latest Tuxera version?

Comment: First I tried to uninstall "NTFS-Config" which was nonsense as I understand now what's the sense of this tool. Then I boldly tried "sudo apt-get install --reinstall ntfs-3g" and it helped :)) I presume it overwrote/added some of the Tuxera-package files with those of the Ubuntu distribution. Later I want to test if I can install the latest Tuxera package again and see if it works.

Comment: Update: though it worked for mounting the drives, the error is still shown in GParted. Nevertheless, it doesn't seem to affect the functionality. I cannot find this error. So if someone has any clue please don't hesitate to answer.